# Hibernate extending entity for read with additional joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have an entity that corresponds to some table in DB

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @OneToMany
  private List<Foo> foos;
...
//getters setters
...
}
```

And I would like to extend that entity for read-only and have additional joins to another table. I need this joins only in one case for specific read user-case:

```
@Entity
public class ExtendedEntity extends MyEntity {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

Just using extensions will create a discriminator column in DB, which I don't need since I'm using the `ExtendedEntity` only for the read. I found I hack with using `@DiscriminatorFormula` that will be resolved to the same Integer value like this:

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("0")
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class MyEntity

@DiscriminatorValue("00")
public class ExtendedEntity extends MyEntity
```

But this really looks like a hack. With using `@MappedSuperclass` I cannot have associations, but this is the main reason I need to extend my entity.

What other options do I have and what are the best practices for this use-case?

Comment: Just put the many-to-many in the existing entity. toMany associations are lazy. Adding a toMany association won't (or at least shouldn't) change anything to the existing code, and won't load anything else from the database.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about this option. But this can pollute my entity with a lot of associations. So if I'm having a lot of cases, I always should fetch the needed association explicitly. I was thinking of having an extended entity that always fetch the needed associations

Comment: Creating a new entity every time you need to fetch additional or different associations clearly doesn't scale. Use specific queries to do that, or use entity graphs or fetch profiles

Comment: @JBNizet not for every time, but for two different cases :) But having all the needed associations I should definitely consider